# How do I set an HTTP proxy through VPN?

Tags: vpn, http

How do I set an HTTP proxy through VPN?

I am currently at a client and they are using a Proxy to connect the users to the internet.

I wondering if it is possible to set an HTTP proxy through VPN.

I installed OpenVPN and tried to set a proxy, but it didn't work.

Does anyone know how to set an HTTP proxy through VPN?

Reason: I want to set a proxy for localhost and change my IP location.

Your help would be so much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is that you’re trying to accomplish? (HTTP) Proxies and VPNs are unrelated network technologies. You can use one or the other or both.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a working VPN without the proxy.  If you haven't setup a VPN yet, do that first.

Then - The VPN you are trying to use will need to connect to the proxy.  This depends on the type of proxy that is being used - if it's a SOCKS proxy, some VPNs can connect "through" it.

Comment: Do you know a VPN that connects to http proxy?